# Get assembly list file while buidling app with profile-guided optimization

Tags: visual-c++

While using PGO to build application(executable), msvc will use linker to finally generate the optmized executable with all the pgo/pgc auxiliary files.

But how could I get assembly list file(as the /Fa /FAsc option) for profile-guided optimization?

Answer (score 0):

When you have a .asm source file in a project
then Configuration Properties should have a
section labeled "Microsoft Macro Assembler".
Under the "Listing" properties it should have a 
choice: "Enable Assembly Generated Code Listing"

If you set it to "Yes" it will add the /Sg option
to the command line for ml.exe

Or add it manually to your custom build properties 
if that's how you're doing it.

"Assembled Code Listing File"
should also be set.